# Trigger option change using option id?

Tags: jquery

I'm successfully triggering the change of options using their values. But I can;t do it using their `id`s (their values aren't fixed, so I need to use the `id`s).

HTML:

```
<select id="ilkoduu">
<option val='1' id='1'>Adana</option>
<option val='2' id='2'>Adıyaman</option>
<option val='3' id='3'>Afyon</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('#ilkoduu').val('3').trigger('change');
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Note that it should be `value="1"`, not `val="1"` (and so on).

Comment: Because the values are not stable and can't figure what they will be.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to look up the value of the option using the option's `id` (which is a pain, because those `id` values start with digits — `#1` is an invalid CSS selector, you have to write it with an escape: `#\31`, and of course if you're writing that in a string literal, you have to escape the backslash: `"#\\31"`):

```
var val = $("#\\31").val();
$("#ilkoduu").val(val).trigger('change');
```

Or all together:

```
$("#ilkoduu").val($("#\\31").val()).trigger('change');
```

Or, actually, you could use the DOM directly for that bit and avoid the selector issue:

```
$("#ilkoduu").val(document.getElementById("1").value).trigger('change');
```

(`getElementById` doesn't use CSS selectors, and so isn't bothered by the `id` starting with a digit.)

---

In general, to avoid having to write ugly escapes like the above, don't start `id` values with digits if you're going to have to use them in CSS selectors. For instance, put an `x` in front of them or something:

```
<select id="ilkoduu">
<option value='1' id='x1'>Adana</option>
<option value='2' id='x2'>Adıyaman</option>
<option value='3' id='x3'>Afyon</option>
</select>
```

And the selector gets a lot clearer:

```
$("#ilkoduu").val($("#x1").val()).trigger('change');
```